# <identifier> expected & .class expected java

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, identifier

I'm a bit new to java so forgive me if I'm making a simple mistake but I am not sure where I am going wrong, the errors I receive are ".class expected, identifier expected, not a statement, ';' expected." I was trying out different ways and received different errors from those ways but I figured these errors would be the easiest to diagnose. Thanks in advance for any responses.
    **The Code:**

```
//main class 
Operation a = new Operation(); 
double area = a.square(double area, double length); // line that receives errors

// Operation class
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Operation
{
    double pi = 3.14;
    double gravity = 9.8;
    double length;
    double width;
    double area;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public double square(double area, double length)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter length of each side of a square:");
        length = keyboard.nextDouble();
        area = length * length;
        System.out.println(area);
        return area;
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be the result of `a.square(double area, double length);`?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the input from the command line so you don't need any parameters in your `square(...)` method. Declare it as:

```
public double square()
{
    double area, length;
    System.out.println("Enter length of each side of a square:");
    length = keyboard.nextDouble();
    area = length * length;
    System.out.println(area);
    return area;
}
```

and call it in the main method like this:

```
double area = a.square();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a method in Java you have to specify the types as you did for `public double square(double area, double length)`.

However when calling the method the types must be omitted. You only pass the variables:

```
double area = a.square(area, length);
```

As Parker_Halo pointed out in his answer, you do not need the parameters at all.

Comment: oh, i totally forgot to explain why it throws any errors xD +1 for that ;)